# Url.Action inside Hangfire job

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hangfire

I have some recurring jobs created with Hangfire and inside these jobs I would like to use Url.Action. It is possible? Or do I have to manually create URLs.

Comment: Have you tried it? Url.Action is from System.Web.Mvc namespace. Try add it and check.

Comment: I have the Object I don't have the reference. It is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hangfire happens outside the context of the site so it won't know the Url.Action.  They recommend to pass it in as a parameter.

Comment: Is there any practise used to set a base url as a global parameter in it on startup or so?

Comment: Perhaps as a configuration setting perhaps.  But otherwise, you would just pass it in as a parameter.

Comment: It's ok when you call it from place where you have request context. But if you are using it for reoccurring job without any request context you have two options - use it from some config file or set it as a global from some service with request context.